# Can a function have a branch cut along the real and also imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, branch-points

Is it possible for a complex function to have a branch cut along the real axis and also the imaginary axis, that cross over like a + sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, why not?  Try $f_1(z) + f_2(z) + f_3(z) + f_4(z)$ where $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$, $f_4$ have branch cuts on the positive real, positive imaginary, negative real and negative imaginary axes respectively.